# Babel preset env not targeting correct env

Tags: babeljs, webpack-2

I may be confused as to what babel-preset-env actually does. My assumption is that it would transpile my code for my targeted browsers including any necessary polyfills. This doesn't appear to be the case in my code though...

My code:

```
import "babel-polyfill"
...
var k = Object.values({ x: 's' });
```

My babel settings:

```
    "presets": [
    [ "env", {
      "useBuiltIns": true,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "IE 10"]
      }
    }]
  ]
```

The transpiled code still contains `Object.values` and IE 10 dies quietly (it does transpile - I can see the rest of the code changing - just seems to target wrong).

Package.json (some of these imports are not in use):

```
"core-js": "^2.5.1",
"opentype.js": "^0.7.2",
"svg.draggable.js": "^2.2.1",
"svg.js": "^2.6.3",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
"babel-register": "^6.24.1",
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
"compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
"imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
"mocha": "^3.5.0",
"webpack": "^3.4.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
```

Comment: Given your update, if you look in the output bundle from webpack, has your `import "babel-polyfill";` been expanded into a `require` call to load things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`babel-preset-env` in its default state only handles converting syntax, not polyfilling standard library functionality.

Sounds like you'll want [`useBuiltins: true`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/tree/1.x#usebuiltins) in your config. You'll also need to follow the other instructions there by installing `core-js` and adding an import for `babel-polyfill`.

Alternatively you can just load `babel-polyfill` itself and not rely on `babel-preset-env` at all.

Comment: So why this in the babel site: "babel-preset-env...automatically determining the Babel plugins and polyfills you need based on your targeted browser or runtime environments."?

Comment: Because it does do all those things, it just doesn't necessarily do them all automatically.

Comment: Still a no go. Updated my question with more data.

Comment: Ah got it working. I had a brain fart and was looking for my code to be transpiled instead of the polyfill presence. I noticed the docs for `useBuiltIns` has choices of "usage" | "entry" | false but not true - though that works. Not sure what true is equal to in this case.

Comment: The docs on the `master` branch are for the current beta. If you follow the link in my answer, it's specifically for the `1.x` branch, which describes it as only having a boolean value.

Comment: What do you mean by "just load `babel-polyfill`"? Do you mean just `npm install babel-polyfill`? Do I also `require` it in `index.js`? Will this work invisibly alongside `@babel/preset-env`? Is this simpler if all I want is to polyfill everything? Thanks